How to fix Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0
I'm encountering a build error when trying to build my React Native app using npm run android. The error message indicates that a dependency (androidx.core:core-ktx or androidx.core:core) requires compiling against API level 34 or later, while my project is currently set to compile against API level 33.
Also I installed react-native-pdf and react-native-blob-util packages for the project.
Here's the relevant part of the error message
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.                                                         

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.           

See https://docs.gradle.org/8.0.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
30 actionable tasks: 25 executed, 5 up-to-date

info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor 


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
   > 2 issues were found when checking AAR metadata:

       1.  Dependency 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0' requires libraries and applications that
           depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
           Android APIs.

           :app is currently compiled against android-33.

           Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
           plugin 7.4.2 is 33.

           Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
           plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
           compileSdkVerion of at least 34.

           Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
           allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
           targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
           minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
           on).

       2.  Dependency 'androidx.core:core:1.12.0' requires libraries and applications that
           depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
           Android APIs.

           :app is currently compiled against android-33.

           Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
           Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
           plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
           compileSdkVerion of at least 34.

           Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
           allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
           targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
           minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
           on).

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 14s

I'd like to keep my project compiling against API level 33. Is there a way to resolve this dependency issue without upgrading the compile SDK version?

Have you tried updating gradle plugin version and  compileSdkVersion ?

after removing react-native-pdf and react-native-blob-util packages app build without errors

You don't need to remove any library. What I am trying to say is update gradle plugin from 7.4.2 to 8.2.2. and after that update compileSdkVersion from 33 to 34.

I had the same problem.
My solution was to use an older version of react-native-pdf and react-native-blob-util:
"react-native-blob-util": "0.19.8",
"react-native-pdf": "6.7.4",

With that, I can compile again with SDK 33.
